# how to load assets,such as .css, .js file, in finatra?

Tags: finatra

I try return a html file by finatra, the file itself loaded success but all assets can't, contains css, ico and js. Browser response 404:can't load resources.
find the document at bottom of the page:
[-com.twitter.finatra.config.assetPath='/public': path to assets](http://twitter.github.io/finatra/v1/docs/configuration.html)

I put public folder under [src/main/resources/public](http://twitter.github.io/finatra/v1/docs/index.html#assets), failed also.  :-(

my code simple as:

```
class Login extends Controller {

  get("/signin") { request: Request =>
    val content = Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource("/forwardend/signin.html")).mkString
    response.created.html(content).toFuture
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve it with some struggle :)
The way is add a controller to deal with all assets. The code as:

```
import com.twitter.finagle.http.Request
import com.twitter.finatra.http.Controller

class Resources extends Controller {
  get("/assets/:*") { request: Request =>
    response.ok.file("/public/" + request.params("*"))
  }
}
```

refer :http://twitter.github.io/finatra/user-guide/files/#file-server
Besides,I try to use below code to change assets path,to make it more pretty,but failed. So I must setting file path with a "/public/" as prefix. If it have a better choice, please point out,thanks.

```
  System.setProperty("com.twitter.finatra.config.assetPath", "src/main/resources/public")
  System.setProperty("local.doc.root", "src/main/resources/public")
```

**UPDATE**
System.setProperty doesn't work. @Christopher thanks remind me.
A way to setting a Flag("doc.root",...) or Flag("local.doc.root",...) is as follow:
1. define a Module

```
object AssetsPathConfigModule extends TwitterModule {
  val keyFileDoc = flag("local.doc.root", "./finatra/src/main/scala/com/myfinatra/public", "The key to use.") // file path
  val keyDoc = flag("doc.root", "/com/myfinatra/public/", "class path") // class path

//@Singleton
  @Provides
  def providesThirdPartyFoo: FileResolver = {
    new FileResolver("", keyDoc())
//  or new FileResolver(keyFileDoc(),"")
  }
}
```

2.add the module to HttpServer's modules seq

```
class HelloWorldServer extends HttpServer {
  override val modules = Seq(
    ...,
    AssetsPathConfigModule
  )
  ...
}
```

3. Resources could be write as

   class Resources extends Controller {
     get("/assets/:*") { request: Request =>
       response.ok.file(request.params("*"))
     }
   }

Answer (score 1):

"com.twitter.finatra.config.assetPath" is for Finatra v1.x and not Finatra 2.x (the latest) which it looks like you are trying to use.

The latest Finatra user-guide details how to serve files: http://twitter.github.io/finatra/user-guide/files/.

If your files are on the classpath, Finatra will find them and you can load them by the path on the classpath, e.g.,

```
get("/file") { request: Request =>
  response.ok.file("/file123.txt")
}
```

If your files are "namespaced" on the classpath, e.g., you put them all under a directory, "/resources" relative to the base classpath you can have Finatra look for them there as well by setting the "-doc.root" flag. This would me you could reference the file as "/file123.txt" rather than "/resources/file123.txt" in your controller (since Finatra knows the directory/namespace).

If you are testing and want to point to files that are somewhere local to your filesystem you can set the "-local.doc.root" flag to the directory containing the assets.

Comment: thanks @Christopher , I have submit a new answer for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

The guides were a bit confusing for me. They are very useful when you want to change settings but I wanted to know how to work with default settings using an example.

let's say your file is stored in: '/src/main/resources/public/hello.jpg'

You can load this directly using fileIO with the following

`getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("samplecards/bcbs_anonymous.jpg").getPath` can be used to return the path of the resource. you can use this information or this code segment accordingly with regular fileIO in scala.

If you're looking to make a finatra response, you can use the following for the example case:

```
get(GetImage) {
  request: ImageRequest => {
    response.ok.file(s"/public/hello.jpg")
  }
}
```

The file requires a string and seems to default that string relative to `{project_folder}/target/scala-x.xx/classes/` in the project folder which is populated with your static assets from the `resources` folder in `src`.